# Visual Studio 2015 Android NDK ARM architecture

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, android-ndk

In Visual Studio 2015 Preview (currently the latest and greatest), you can compile C/C++ code for Android. This generates .a libraries (which is correct).

In the export settings you can export either for ARM or x86.

However, in the regular Android NDK you have to target either armeabi or armeabi-v7a.

The question, for which I haven't been able to find any answer yet, is whether the Visual Studio 2015 preview exports for armeabi or armeabi-v7a architectures.

Does anyone know for which architecture of ARM does VS 2015 Preview exports as?

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it defaults to arm, possibly with a configuration option hidden somewhere.  One way to find out would be to open the resulting .apk as a zip file and see in which abi-named folder the resulting file (which needs to be an .so for normal usage) ends up.  Presumably you could also feed the same source files to the NDK compiler (possibly a generated "stand alone toolchain" if you want more versatility.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will look at the generated apk to see what I get from VS.

Comment: So this approach didn't work. The files VS is outputting from the C/C++ code are .a files, which is what I'm expecting. However, when I generate the application (and basically when I compile the app) the .a files get placed into a larger .so library. This means that when I expand the .apk file, I only see the .so files in the architecture I specified on the Application.mk file, and not the .a files anywhere. In other words, this doesn't answer the question of what architecture the .a files are.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio 2015 Preview supports x86 and armeabi-v7a architectures for android development.  This can be deduced by looking carefully at the project's include and library directories.